# IE11 Angular-CLI source maps not working

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer-11, angular-cli, office-js, source-maps

[image: Source maps are showing up in the JavaScript bundle]

Using Angular-CLI 1.0 and Angular 4, I am unable to get source maps working despite having `//# sourceMappingURL=main.bundle.js.map` in the bundled JavaScript.  Does anyone know a work around to get the sourcemaps working in IE-11?  Normally this wouldn't be a huge issue, I'd just switch to firefox or chrome. But I'm developing an Excel add-in with the Office-js api, and it uses an embedded IE11 browser to display the add-in, so I'm stuck with it.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch but could that line with //# be getting minified in such a way that the proceeding minified content shares a line that causes errors. For Example --> //# here is the end of the file above <NO CTRL-LF> var thisVarsNowInTheCommentButFromAnotherFile..

Comment: That's a good thought, but I don't think that's what is happening here. That screenshot is from the debugger while running the app and is showing the already bundled file in its final (dev) form. That could be an issue when compiling for prod though.

Comment: @Jolleyboy were you ever able to figure out the problem? I have similar configuration and source maps just stopped working. Chrome works, IE does not. Thanks.

Comment: Saddly no.  I'm just spelunking in my bundle files and making excessive console.logs.

Comment: @Jolleyboy I won't put this as the answer because you asked about Angular CLI but I do have a configuration that works without using Angular CLI and instead using my own webpack config file. What I have found that works is using  `webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin` with the option `noSources: true`. This allows breakpoints to be hit in the actual .ts files in Visual Studio. In your case, you can `eject` the Angular CLI and take over the configuration which isn't that easy to follow but I do know it uses the option `"devtool": "source-map"` instead of the `SourceMapDevToolPlugin`

Comment: and the `"devtool": "source-map"` option did not work for debugging the .ts files.  Note if you do try the `eject` option, **do it in a copy of your project to test it out first because once you eject you can't go back**.  Also, you might want to tag your question with `office-js` and that team will see your question.

Comment: @JimBarrett Excellent news!  Thank you for sharing your solution.

Comment: @Jolleyboy let me know if it works for you then I will move my comments to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Jolleyboy Did this solution work for you?

Comment: @Zze / JimBarrett It didn't end up working for me.
I ended up ejecting and using the source-map-loader plugin for webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that there were multiple `//#sourceMappingURL` comments in the bundled files.  To fix this, you can use the [source-map-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader) for Webpack to extract those comments and feed them to the webpack devtool in order to create a master source-map file.  This is then linked at the end of the bundle.  Now there is only one `//#sourceMappingURL` comment in the file as IE11 expects, and things work swimmingly.

Here is how I did it:

1. [I ejected from the Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject)  ***Warning, this kicks you out of the Angular-CLI, making you responsible for managing your own webpack config, among other things. This is irreversible.*** 
   `ng eject`
2. `npm install source-map-loader`
3. I edited my webpack config to add this:

```
{
  //...
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        enforce: "post"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With this setup, I am able to use breakpoints in the F12 tools, using the sourcemaps.

If you want to go one step further and improve your stacktraces (like Chrome does) you can use [stacktrace.js](https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js/) to make frames and translate them with the sourcemaps. This was a bit of a pain, and the solution is too long to post here

Comment: It might be useful to mention [what `ng eject` does (namely, **breaks the CLI**)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6302#issuecomment-301225384) for people who aren't familiar with it and copy-paste it into a terminal, run it, and promptly freak out.